# How much to charge to organise a photo shot

Tags: price

A company I worked for has contacted me to organize a photo shot where the end product will be used in marketing materials. I have done this before while on payroll; however, this time around they are requesting a cost estimate including my fee.

As far as the shoot, it is a small shoot. One location, one subject and the requesting company is large scale enterprise.

How can I determine how much to charge for this job?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of looking at this:

1. Determine your price, how much do you want for this project to make it worth your while? Do you want an hourly rate or a fixed price?
2. How much is the customer willing to pay? This could be more than option 1. Find out what similar shoots cost for corporate clients, and decide on what you think you can get.

Ask around, use linkedin, twitter, other fora. Ask colleagues, friends. And my advice: go for option 1, decide what you think would be a good price regardless of what others may charge corporate clients.

Answer (score -1):

If the company is a enterprise type of business you should charge them by hour, list down your own expenses and the itemized things they need like, raw copies of photos, number of shots etc. Then by which, you can have an idea on how much the whole amount would be, most likely around 25-35$ per hour for the shoot as an estimate then if they would request for discounts its a round off on your part.